# Singularity arguments conflict with my bioinformatics tool arguments

Tags: docker, dockerfile, bioinformatics, singularity-container

**EDIT: documentation given by the informatic administration was shitty, old version of singularity, now the order of arguments is different and the problem is solved.**

To make my tool more portable, and because I have to use it on a cluster, I have to put my bioinformatics tool at disposal for docker. Tool is located [here](https://github.com/Louis-MG/MetaDBGWAS). The docker hub is 007ptar007/metadbgwas, if you want to experience with it. The Dockerfile is in the repo, and to make it easier to everyone :

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
USER root
COPY ./install_docker.sh ./
RUN chmod +x ./install_docker.sh && sh ./install_docker.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/MetaDBGWAS/metadbgwas.sh"]
ENV PATH="/MetaDBGWAS/:${PATH}"
```

And the install_docker.sh script contains :

```
apt-get update
apt install -y libgatbcore-dev libhdf5-dev libboost-all-dev libpstreams-dev zlib1g-dev g++ cmake git r-base-core
Rscript -e "install.packages(c('ape', 'phangorn'))"
Rscript -e "install.packages('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sgearle/bugwas/master/build/bugwas_1.0.tar.gz', repos=NULL, type='source')"
git clone --recursive https://github.com/Louis-MG/MetaDBGWAS.git
cd MetaDBGWAS
sed -i "51i#include <limits>" ./REINDEER/blight/robin_hood.h #temporary fix for REINDEER compilation
sh install.sh
```

The problem :
My tool parses the command line, and needs a verbose (`-v`, or `--verbose`) argument. It also needs to reject unknown arguments; anything that isn't used by the tool causes the help message to be printed in the standard output and exits. To use the tool, I need to mount volumes were the data is; using `-v /path/to/files:/input` option:

```
singularity run docker://007ptar007/metadbgwas --volumes '/path/to/data:/inputd/:/input' --files /input --strains /input/strains --threads 8 --output ~/output
```

But my tool sees this as a bad `-v` option value or the `--volume` as an unknown option. I can't change this on my tool. How do I solve this conflict ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put any arguments intended for singularity - such as the volume mounting - before the name of the image you want to run (e.g. the docker image you specify in your command):

```
singularity run -v '/path/to/data:/input' docker://007ptar007/metadbgwas --files /input --strains /input/strains --threads 8 --output ~/output
```

Comment: Actually the documentation that was given to me was old and full of mistakes, so the singularity path given was the one to 3.1.1, which had that problème, so I finally figured that out and yes, it worked with a different order. Thank you for your help anyway.